# Suggest a material which can produce heat with DC current

Tags: material-science

Please suggest me a material which can produce heat with DC current and can be turned into a sheet. And should be low of cost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggest a material which can produce heat when dc current is applied](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377803/)

Answer (score 1):

Steel, believe it or not, will create large amounts of heat energy when electrical current passes through it. The steel sheet should be very thin, less than a millimeter in thickness, maybe thinner. Although I must warn you that it is very hard to get a single sheet of any material to heat up from electrical current passing through it. A better idea would be to run thin steel wire *under* a metal plate, or sheet, and heat up the sheet that way.

Comment: there are a number of sheet heaters available which use thick carbon black-loaded paint or plastic applied to paper made of fiberglass or other heat-resistant material, and laminated with an electrical insulator.  they are very inexpensive and can easily be cut to different sizes. you will find them in yogurt makers, waterbed heaters and the like.